# Is there an analog for the SwiftUI's Window class for macOS v.12 (Monterey)?

Tags: macos, swiftui, macos-monterey

I'm using the following code for my macOS app to limit the app only to a single window:

```
@main
struct MygApp: App {    

    var body: some Scene {
                
        //To insure that only one instance is shown
        Window("My app", id: "idMyAppWnd")
        {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear {
                    
                }
        }
}
```

I need this app to work on macOS Monterey (v.12). But when I compile it with `macOS Deployment Target` set to `macOS 12.0`, I'm getting the error:

> 'Window' is only available in macOS 13.0 or newer

What shall I use instead?